# What is the meaning of `! -d` in this Bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Simple question, I don't understand what the `!` and `-d` in the below statement means.

```
if [ ! -d $directory ]
```

Comment: `[` is also the `test` command, so read this, as "if test NOT directory $dir" ... then do something. Good luck.

Comment: aside: needs to be `[ ! -d "$directory" ]` to be correct; without the quotes, it'll behave badly if your directory name has spaces or can be expanded as a glob.

Comment: BTW, next time you have some shell you don't understand, try copying-and-pasting it into http://explainshell.com/ (albeit, in this case, either without the `if`, or adding a `; then : "something here"; fi` at the end to make the syntax correct).

Comment: Thanks for explainshell.com. So far, I knew only about shellcheck.net

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`-d` is a operator to test if the given directory exists or not.

For example, I am having a only directory called /home/sureshkumar/test/.

The directory variable contains the "/home/sureshkumar/test/"

```
if [ -d $directory ]
```

This condition is true only when the directory exists. In our example, the directory exists so this condition is true.

I am changing the directory variable to  "/home/a/b/".
This directory does not exist.

```
if [ -d $directory ]
```

Now this condition is false. If I put the `!` in front if the directory does not exist, then the if condition is true. If the directory does exists then the `if [ ! -d $directory ]` condition is false.

The operation of the ! operator is if the condition is true, then it says the condition is false. If the condition is false then it says the condition is true. This is the work of ! operator.

```
if [ ! -d $directory ]
```

This condition true only if the $directory does not exist. If the directory exists, it returns false.

Comment: Note that the `-d` test also fails if the named file exists but is a regular file, or is something else more esoteric (FIFO, block special, character special, etc).  If the name is a symlink and points to a directory, it passes; otherwise it fails.

Answer (score 7):

The brackets are the test executable, the exclamation mark is a negation, and the `-d` option checks whether the variable `$directory` is a directory.

From [man test](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

```
-d FILE
       FILE exists and is a directory

! EXPRESSION
       EXPRESSION is false
```

The result is an if statement saying "if `$directory` is not a directory"

Comment: well -- whether the result of string-splitting and glob-expanding the variable `directory`'s contents names a (single) directory, rather. If you want to check whether those contents correspond with a single directory name when interpreted literally, without globbing or string-splitting first applied, more quotes would be needed.

Answer (score 5):

- `!` negates the condition.
- `-d` option checks `$directory` is a directory or not.

Answer (score 3):

`!` means not

`-d` means test if directory exists

So, `if [ ! -d $directory ]` means if `$directory` does not exist, or $directory isn't a directory (maybe a file instead).

Usually this is followed by a statement to create the directory, such as

```
if [ ! -d $directory ]; then
  mkdir $directory
fi
```

Comment: `mkdir $directory` won't work well if your directory already exists as a file. And if the concern is whether it doesn't exist at all, `mkdir -p "$directory"` with no preceding test is the best-practice idiom to handle the case.

Comment: ...failing to quote the expansion, by contrast, is just plain flat-out wrong. If having assigned `directory="My Documents"` you run `mkdir $directory`, you get **two** directories created, one named `My` and the other named `Documents`, and `[ ! -d $directory ]` becomes equivalent to `[ ! -d "My" "Directory" ]` -- syntactically invalid, since, `-d` expects only one argument to follow, not two.

Answer (score 2):

`-d` is a test operator in bash and when you put `!` before test operator - its negating the same

http://www.techtrunch.com/2011/11/25/test-operators-bash/